# InversifyJS : can not bind using interface

Tags: oop, typescript, visual-studio-code, inversion-of-control, inversifyjs

I am trying to use inversify JS to inject dependencies on TypeScript App. I started by using the example of https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS page :

```
// file interfaces.ts
interface Warrior {
    fight(): string;
}

// file types.ts
const TYPES = {
    Warrior: Symbol("Warrior")
};
export { TYPES };

// file entities.ts
import { injectable, inject } from "inversify";
import "reflect-metadata";
import { Warrior } from "./interfaces"
import { TYPES } from "./types";

@injectable()
class WarriorImpl implements Warrior {
    public constructor(){
    }
    public fight() { return "I fight"; }
}
export { WarriorImpl };

// file inversify.config.ts
import { Container } from "inversify";
import TYPES from "./types";
import { Warrior } from "./interfaces";
import { WarriorImpl } from "./entities";
const myContainer = new Container();
myContainer.bind<Warrior>(TYPES.Warrior).to(WarriorImpl);
export { myContainer };
```

I applied what is provided in the example but Vscode and `tsc` failed at the binding line by showing this error `[ts] Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments. [ts] Cannot find name 'Warrior'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is clean and correct all you have to do is to upgrade your typescript version in your `package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
   "typescript": "3.9.3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to export the interface for it to be imported:

   ```
   // file interfaces.ts
   export interface Warrior {
       fight(): string;
   }
   ```
2. Your import in `inversify.config.ts` should be:

   ```
   import { TYPES } from "./types";
   ```
3. Make sure you have actually installed the library (`npm install inversify`). The error `Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments` is sue to missing type information.

Comment: I applied what you provided, the problem is about the use of diamond operator with interface name <Warrior>. I don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: Are you sure TypeScript is able to find the typings for the library? Are you getting intellisense in VS Code when you type `const myContainer = new Container(); myContainer.`?

Comment: `tsc` command shows the same error. It's not related to VScode.